# ExpandableListView update every 2 seconds

Tags: task, adapter, expandablelistview

I know that this problem is due to update the data every 2sec.

The point is that I have an adapter that shows me `ExpandableListView` and parallel downloading data from the site. I have a function (timer) who takes every 2 seconds update my data (`notifydatasetChanged`).

For this reason, if I change the value in seekbar I cut my slider.

Does anybody have an idea how to update the data? 1 idea -> update only some data 2 idea -> another way of renovation

Please help :)

I don't know what I can do to update only row in expandable list view some row but not all.

Comment: Why every 2 seconds ? Assuming we talk about Android, you should call `notifydatasetChanged` every time the dataset has been changed

Comment: I'm downloading the data from the webserver every second and make-up the data on their premises.
At the same time I run the timer at 2sec, which causes me notifydatasetchanged method.

Comment: But why don't you update the moment you make-up the data ? If you believe the fault is because of the 2 seconds, why not remove the timer and call `notifydatasetChanged` every time you create data and see if it is really because of the 2 seconds

Comment: Yeah, but if i expand for example the first group and i wait, look for this, i want to update this data every ot 2sec, becase it is temperature